# Need an ImageMagick script converted to Imagick

Tags: imagemagick, imagick, imagemagick-convert

I have the following piece of code in ImageMagick from Fred's script

```
scale=`convert xc: -format "%[fx:($ww-1)/($topwidth-1)]" info:`
```

I already have the variables $ww and $topwidth calculated. I can't get the $scale variable populated

Comment: Please see my licensing information if you are rewriting one of my scripts for commercial use. This command is just a calculation using ImageMagick fx:. But there is no reason you cannot do the in PHP directly. `$scale=($ww-1)/($topwidth-1)`

Comment: Yes, Fred. Once I am successful in rewriting the script in PHP, I will buy your script before putting it to commercial use. How can I get some help from you in rewriting some part of your script? Only through SO?

Comment: Contact me at my email address (in red) on my web page at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.php. However, I am not an expert on Imagick.